# (Android)saving apk files in internal storage and install trying, get an parsing error

Tags: android, installation, apk

I'm trying to get `apk` file from `usb storage` and save `internal storage` in my app.

I saved apk file by using:

```
FileOutputStream fout = _context.openFileOutput(filePath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And then I tried to install apk with:

```
private void installApk(String path) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

But I got an error.

`There is a Problem Parsing the Package`

I tried to use:

```
FileOutputStream fout = _context.openFileOutput(filePath, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

And It worked well.

Why `MODE_PRIVATE` cause paring error?

Answer (score 0):

if where you saved apk is path to internal data space of your application then MODE_PRIVATE flag will be prevent any other application can access your apk file (only you can access it).

Comment: Everything(save and install) happens in only one application. So I think MODE_PRIVATE will work properly. But not working.